# Disclosure Indicator on Custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have a custom `UIView` subclass. I'd like to add the disclosure indicator icon to it that is so easy to add to a `UITableViewCell`. Is there any way to do this?

**Edit**

I'm hoping to do this without the use of a `UIButton` and definitely without the use of a `UITableViewCell`. I understand that modifying my custom `UIView` to be a custom `UIButton` would allow me to just set the `buttonType` property but for my case, this seems less elegant than doing it all within a `UIView`.

Comment: `UITableViewCell` has a property accessoryType that you can set to UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator.

Comment: @bbarnhart Yes as I mentioned in the question I know it is very easy to add to a `UITableViewCell`. However I was hoping to do this all within the context of a UIView if I could.

Comment: The `UITableViewCell` disclosure indicator image is not an accessible asset.  You should use your own image.

Comment: @bbarnhart Yes I was thinking of that, was hoping not to have to do that since now I would have to maintain my own image and make sure it looked similar to the default iOS icon image. They really don't expose those images anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the `UIView` and add an `UIImageView` with the disclosure indicator you prefer as a subview.

Hope it helps!